# How do I change the loaded map and config files on a rented Counter Strike: Global Offensive server?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, server-administration, source-engine

I just rented a fresh game server, and performed my initial setup.

The server is loading *de_dust* on startup, and I would like it to load *de_nuke*. I would then like it to load the ESL config. I tried to resolve the problem by adding

```
exec esl.cfg
changelevel "de_dust2"
```

into the *server.cfg*, but it seems like the server is not executing these commands.

Have I done it incorrectly, or am I best to contact the server admin?

Comment: Welcome to the Arqade! :D

Please keep in mind that while we can help you with game related questions, there is a good chance your issue is with the server, and falls out of our control. 

I have edited your question to ask for confirmation the problem is not on your end, but if your all G you really need to get in touch with whoever you rent the server from.

Feel free to hit "edit" again if you want to see how I've done all the markup.

Comment: You MUST run the `map` command instead of `changelevel` to set the starting map.  It apparently does some internal logic that `changelevel` doesn't that is required for the server to finish starting up.

Comment: Having said that, any further map changes should be done using `changelevel` as `map` disconnects all players.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're editing the wrong file. Counter Strike Global Offensive (CS:GO) is working in other way than source do.

### Exec cfg

To make the server exec you `esl.cfg` you've to add your exec command to the `autoexec.cfg`

### Mapcycle

There is gamemodes.txt file around which you've to override and to do so you've to make a gamemodes_server.txt which looks like this (standard format in CS:GO)

```
// Values here override the default gamemodes.txt 

"GameModes_Server.txt"
{
    "gameTypes"
    {
        "classic"
        {
            "gameModes"
            {
                "casual"
                {
                    "convars"
                    {
                        "sv_allow_votes"                    "0"
                        "mp_roundtime"                      "4"
                        "add cvars here"                    "or under mode u want to run"
                    }

                    "mapgroupsMP"                       // List of mapgroups valid for this game mode
                    {
                        "mg_bomb"       ""
                        "mg_hostage"        ""
                        "mg_dust"       ""
                    }
                }

                "competitive"
                {
                    "convars"
                    {
                        "mp_startmoney"                         "800"
                        "mp_maxmoney"                           "16000"
                        "mp_match_end_restart"                  "0"
                        "add other cvars u want"                "under gamemod u want to run"
                    }
```

the point here are those lines:

```
"mapgroupsMP"
{
    "mg_bomb"       ""
    "mg_hostage"    ""
    "mg_dust"       ""
}
```

In such mapgroups you can fill in maps and map cycles like the mapcycle.txt back in Source.

To create such a mapgroup you've to do the following:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Map groups
//
// To use a mapgroup, it needs to be defined in a keyvalues
// block such as the example below, as well as listed in the 
// 'mapgroupsMP' block within the game mode that will run it,
// such as the example above.
//
// Then launch the server with '+mapgroup MAPGROUPNAME'
//
// Example:
//
// srcds -game csgo +game_mode 1 +mapgroup mg_bomb_se +map de_nuke_se
//
//
// Check the developer wiki for updated community info
// https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive_Dedicated_Servers
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    "mapgroups"
    {
        "mg_custom"                                 // mapgroup definition
        {
            "name"          "mg_custom"
            "maps"
            {
                "de_dust"       ""
                "de_aztec"      ""
                "cs_italy"      ""
                "de_dust2"      ""
                "de_train"      ""
                "cs_office"     ""
                "de_inferno"        ""
                "de_nuke"       ""
                "cs_estate"     ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use the server startcommand like `+mapgroup mg_custom +map de_dust2` to start your own mapcycle.

### Important!

You **could** just edit the gamemode.txt but those changes will be resetted as soon as you get an update.

If you need more help, you'll find some on [**Valves Developer Community page.**](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive_Dedicated_Servers)